Ensuring Proper Benchmark Results Inside Unity Editor, Without The Profiler
So I've run into a situation where I have two systems. One system is an A* module and the other is a path-finding system which handles requests, uses the A* module, and then returns a populated path object. My concern is that they're both running at bout 10ms, or slightly over. In my opinion this is too close to be a valid result because the A* module in isolation running at 10ms means the entire system should be taking more time, even if it's not much longer. But it's literally like fractions of a millisecond and the path request system isn't even optimized yet. It's actually using async functions which alone come with overhead. My concern initially was that the task scheduler was producing the illusion that they were finishing at the same time. However, I have stripped any usage of the tasking, async/await and the TPL in general from the isolated A* module and I'm still receiving these results.
I should note that I am using the stopwatch class. However, I am generating the time by calculating the number of ticks and the frequency for as high precision as possible that the stopwatch will allow. I've looked into things like Benchmark .Net and they also seem to rely on the stopwatch in that way, so I don't think the actual accuracy of the time is what is in play here.
My second thought was that using the Manual Reset Event inside the system benchmark, the system as a whole, was preventing the stopwatch itself from, continuing to tick. So I've parallelized it so that the following manual reset event that is required to wait for the path-finding system to accurately be measured, due to it's parallel and event-based architecture, will not effect te stopwatch. I can't simply wait for the function to finish. The MRE has to be set once an completion event is received. This too, works fine, in terms of functionality. But again, the almost identical run times leads me to believe something else is wrong.
Which leads to question one, is running the stop watch in parallel going to prevent the stop watch from being halted when the MRE is hit? I would assume it would and I can't find any sources that say otherwise.
Secondly, while the path-finding system does rely on the task-parallel library and scheduling is expected, the A* module in isolation is completely free of any async functionality. The way it's been designed is to run sequentially so that I can ensure all path-finding is happening on a single thread allowing me to parallelize it with as little thread-saftey concerns as possible and the overhead involved with concurrent collections, be they backed by non-contiguous memory or requiring locking mechanisms, and that sort of thing. So the A* module does not rely on any type of async/await state machine when run directly from the benchmark module.
And yet, they still both run at about 10ms, give or take a few very small fractions. I'm even less trusting of the unity profiler for anything other than memory monitoring given the actual path-finding system can take less time than the A* module that it relies on.
So I'm hoping someone can point out some things I may be missing? I'm wondering if simply parallelizing the class that uses the stopwatch is not enough and am intended on using an external call to the query performance counter and just taking the 300-500ns hit so I'm sure that there's no halted execution caused by the manual reset event.
I'm also considering loading up benchmark .Net but as with the unit test packages, they tend to be very limited in the capability when it comes to integrating with unity. I know unity has its own type of scheduling system for co-routines and jobs as well as the same for async/await as well. However, the A* module and the path-finding system as a whole are completely custom classes that are not monobehaviors, do not rely on life-cycle, and do not use coroutines.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can investigate this further? I've finally got the foundations down and am looking to optimize the systems individually, and while it may just be the caste that the request system is so light-weight that the A* module takes up 99% of the cycles required, but I'm kind of doubting it given that the architecture uses a concurrent-queue type system to processing incoming requests and is also where the async/await functionality is contained. Again, my next step is essentially going to be using the QueryPerformanceCounter to ensure that there's no issues with threading, taking the extern call hit, and then optimizing the A* module to see if the time changes. But I find the idea that these are running at very similar times to be suspicious and indicative of something.
So I was wondering if anyone had run into a similar situation in the past or was aware of any unity behavior that might explain this given Unity's many, how shall we say, eccentricities. Though I haven't been able to find anything about unity having a scheduling behavior like the task scheduler and the best answer I can get is that there may be overhead. But overhead would imply both would be slower and it's very odd they run at the exact same time, give or take a few hundredths of a millisecond. If anyone has any other suggestions that might help me narrow down this behavior.
Much obliged, cheers ladies and gentlemen.

There's a lot of text here for a reader to interpret to try to reconstruct how they think your code is working. You can probably attract answers faster (and more accurate answers to boot) if you share some code samples. It doesn't have to be your full code, just a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example that shows how you're running and instrumenting this routine. You can replace the actual A* algorithm with a call to sleep, or a for loop that adds a few thousand random numbers, just to keep it concise. This will make it very fast for a reader to get an unambiguous understanding of your situation.

Thank you for the suggestion, I will keep that in mind. I do tend to just go stream of consciousness on ya'. The issue I have is stopping to process means I end up losing some of it because my short-term memory has taken some damage from some recent health issues. But, I'll try to figure out how to do that in the future without handing my code out to be assimilated by the LLMs.

I'll admit, it was a pretty bad explanation and there ended up being no problem at all, I just couldn't believe the results. So my apologies. I appreciate the patience.

A few hundredths of a millisecond seems like reasonable overhead for threading, but it really depends. Unless the non-A* code does a lot, it's probably not going to take anywhere near 10 milliseconds.
You could try reducing the size of the environment. There's definitely tons of overhead if it's still slow in a tiny environment.
If you have an intel processor, you could use VTune to verify your measurements. There are probably similar profiling tools for other kinds of processors.
The Stopwatch class doesn't require a running thread to keep ticking. Instead, it checks a time intended for this kind of thing in the computer's hardware - see the remarks section of the documentation. It might be the same as QueryPerformanceCounter.

Thanks for at least responding. More than I actually expect out of stack these days. I looked into the QPC but it seems to be the same resolution as the stopwatch and the stopwatch seems to actually be based upon it. Though I haven't actually looked into why you encounter overhead for the QPC that you don't from the stopwatch, but that's an entirely different question. As to the thread the stopwatch was on, it was more me just being unable to believe the benchmarks were just that dang close. But it turns out, after isolating it, the request system is really like a 0.4ms overhead.

As far as the A* code goes, it is literally 10ms out of the 10.x ms - the test I've got up is essentially worst case scenario and it has to explore dang near every node, just so because I'm more concerned with the that worst-case rather than best-case. It's just a 50x50 test and it explores about 2400/2500 tiles. I honestly just through the stop watch in another thread because I literally couldn't believe the overhead of the path finding system was as light weight as it was. I assumed I had to have done something wrong. But I've isolated it and confirmed it.

Anyway, thanks for the response, and thanks for being a decent human being. It was actually much kinder than I expected from this place. I assumed my tests had to be wrong, so I was just throwing things at it to see if anything stuck. I appreciate the suggestions, and the information.

Marking this as the correct answer, just because there was no actual issue in the first place and it correctly points out that the stopwatch class functionality is not thread dependent. (Again, I just couldn't believe it.)
